# What does "@" mean before a string?

Tags: c#

What does "@" mean before a string?

I saw this notation with paths:

```
string myfolder = @"C:\Users\";
```

But also with normal strings.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16635176/what-is-a-verbatim-string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means it's a literal string, so won't treat `\` as an escape character, for example. [This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms228362.aspx) should help you understand it better.

Comment: Not sure why you got downvoted... People seem to be so trigger-happy lately.