# Solution for Remove a string with extension word in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Input:-
Attachment\Internal\1508001_1013422155337804_2224943720795643293_n.jpg

Ouptput:-
Attachment\Internal

how to Remove that extension word (for ex: 1508001_1013422155337804_2224943720795643293_n.jpg) itself..

Comment: does google not work on your end..?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Path.GetDirectoryName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3x9wbdze(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(
    @"Attachment\Internal\1508001_1013422155337804_2224943720795643293_n.jpg");
```

Note the use of a [*verbatim string literal*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16635176/what-is-a-verbatim-string) to remove the need to escape the backslashes.

Comment: It should work for any path. You only gave one example and gave no mention of dynamism in your question...