# Split using regex with (#something)

Tags: c#, regex

I want to split above string using regex in c#

**Input :**

```
"some1 Text (#something) someothertext (#something) some3 Text"
```

**Expected Output:**

```
some1 Text
someothertext
some3 Text
```

**My Code**

```
string str = "some1 Text (#something) someothertext (#something) some3 Text";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\(([^)]*)\)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var result = regex.Split(str);
```

**Output**

```
some1 Text
#something
someothertext
#something
some3 Text
```

Comment: Why are you mentioning `(#something)` when the values you want to match are `some1` and `Text`? Is this the delimiter between fields? What is the pattern in this string? Fields separated by `(#...)` and key values separated by a single space?

Comment: Please give a more specific example including some code you have tried

Comment: Yes. i want field separated by (#...)

Comment: @MaximilianAst that is not expected output

Comment: You can just ignore it and match the content, eg `\w+ \w+`. This will return the intended output.

Comment: (#...) is the delimiter between fields

Comment: And the fields? What do they contain? Why can't you just use `\w+ \w+` ?

Comment: So what's your problem? Is it the use of regex to split a string or to build a proper regex for your problem? Stackoverflow isn't a code writing service, so please show your attempt.

Comment: I am not able to make expression...i have tried this Regex regex = new Regex(@"\(([^)]*)\)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

Comment: @umeshgangwar and I already provided a pattern that works. Did you try it? Is your example *real*? Does your data use unseparated strings or something else? *Be specific*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String input = "some1 Text (#One) some2 other (#something) some3 Text";
String pattern = @"\(#.*?\)";
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(pattern);
string output = regex.Replace(input, System.Environment.NewLine);
```

Breakdown of regex: **\(#.*?\)**

- Escaped Left Parenthesis: **\\(**
- Pound symbol: #
- Match anything for any number of characters: **.***
- Non-Greedy Operator: **?**
- Escaped Right Parenthesis:
  **\\)**

Comment: This will match the delimiters, not the fields

Comment: That's the idea - replace the delimiters with new lines.

Comment: instead of `"\\(.*?\\)"` you can use a [verbatim string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16635176/what-is-a-verbatim-string) instead: `@"\(.*?\)"` it is easier to read.

Comment: `@"\(#.*?\)"` is perhaps more accurate as all the delimiters start with a hash sign.

Comment: why not `(\(#.*?\))` ?

Comment: @Heki this is the expression which i need...delimiter is always started with #...thanks...i am very new to Stack Overflow....i dont know how to mark answer.... :-)

Comment: I'm not sure of the larger context of the problem, but adding a # for a match seems very reasonable here.

Answer (score 0):

You can match both the separators and the fields with `(?<field>[^\(]+)(?<delim>\(#[^\)]*\))?`. You can refer to each part by name, eg `field` or `delim`. For example:

```
var input = "some1 Text (#One) some2 other (#something) some3 Text";
var pattern = @"(?<field>[^\(]+)(?<delim>\(#[^\)]*\))??";

var matches = Regex.Matches(input,pattern);
var fields=from match in matches.OfType<Match>()
           select match.Group["field"].Value;
foreach(var field in fields)
{
    Console.WriteLine(field);
}
```

Results:

```
some1 Text  
 some2 other  
 some3 Text
```

The expression captures everything that isn't a `(` as the field. Anything between `(# and`)` is captured as the delimiter.

Captured doesn't mean that a string is generated. The loop only retrieves the values of the fields