# How to write a multi-table update for MySql in C# (Currently functional, looking for elegance)

Tags: c#, mysql

Is there a clean way to combine the four UDPATE statements across four tables into a single statement?

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cxId", tboxId.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cxName", tboxName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", tboxAddress.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address2", tboxAddress2.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", tboxCity.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@zip", tboxZip.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country", tboxCountry.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", tboxPhone.Text);

Console.WriteLine("tblCustomer Update attempting...");
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE customer " +
"SET customerName = @cxName " +
"WHERE customerId = @cxId";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Console.WriteLine("tblAddress Update attempting...");
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE address " +
"RIGHT JOIN customer ON customer.addressId = address.addressId " +
"SET address.address = @address, " +
"address.address2 = @address2, " +
"address.postalCode = @zip, " +
"address.phone = @phone " +
"WHERE customer.customerId = @cxId";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Console.WriteLine("tblCity Update attempting...");
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE city " +
"RIGHT JOIN address ON address.cityId = city.cityId " +
"RIGHT JOIN customer ON customer.addressId = address.addressId " +
"SET city.city = @city " +
"WHERE customer.customerId = @cxId";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Console.WriteLine("tblCountry Update attempting...");
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE country " +
"RIGHT JOIN city ON city.countryId = country.countryId " + 
"RIGHT JOIN address ON address.cityId = city.cityId " +
"RIGHT JOIN customer ON customer.addressId = address.addressId " +
"SET country.country = @country " +
"WHERE customer.customerId = @cxId";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I have the included series of UPDATE statements, which work as intended but are (by my personal judgement) super gross (right joins) and clunky. I wanted to create a single UPDATE that would affect the same outcome, but was unable to figure out how to manage the joins without a "Not unique table/alias" error, even when I used table aliases.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you choose `RIGHT JOIN` instead of simply `JOIN`?

Comment: Also you can use an `@` verbatim string and embed newlines to make it more readable

Comment: Thank you @BillKarwin that's a great point, that's an odd habit I seem to have developed, I'm still very early on in my SQL journey. There's no functional reason for it, I think it helps me think of what "direction" the join is going, but `JOIN` would be appropriate.

Comment: Thank you @Charlieface I took a look over at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16635176/what-is-a-verbatim-string) to learn more and this is VERY helpful. Appreciate the recommendation!